I got an error in REACT NATIVE CLI App Installing

AwesomeProject@0.0.1 android
react-native run-android

info Installing the app...

Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle: 8.6


Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
8 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 4 up-to-date
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'.


Cannot access output property 'sourceOutputDir' of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:disable-state-tracking in the Gradle documentation.
java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\suren\OneDrive\Desktop\BLE FINAL\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\awesomeproject\BuildConfig.java: not a regular file


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 7s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. > Cannot access output property 'sourceOutputDir' of task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. Accessing unreadable inputs or outputs is not supported. Declare the task as untracked by using Task.doNotTrackState(). For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/incremental_build.html#sec:disable-state-tracking in the Gradle documentation. > java.io.IOException: Cannot snapshot C:\Users\suren\OneDrive\Desktop\BLE FINAL\AwesomeProject\android\app\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\awesomeproject\BuildConfig.java: not a regular file * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 7s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig FAILED
if you get the above error then use below Command
After your project Main Path
>>>>>cd android
>>>>>./gradlew clean
again go to your project Main Path
After Build your React Native APP then it Works well
